# Why is this answer spam?

Tags: support, review-audits, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits, spam

I failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17595044) review audit because the system thinks it is spam. I was then banned from review.

> [image: screenshot of the answer]

Why is this answer spam? I don't understand why this answer is spam and I believe that it is not spam. The post does recommend a tool, but it is a mainstream tool by Oracle and the poster does give some context regarding using the tool. The poster references a blog, but there is no indication that the poster is affiliated with the blog and the blog is used to support the poster's content, not substitute for it. The post appears to be more of a low-quality "i can has cheap repz?" answer than spam, and the correct behavior for those posts is to downvote them, not delete them.

Evidence in my favor:

- The user currently exists (aren't the accounts of spammers usually summarily deleted?).
- The user had their account for over four years before they posted this answer. That's a *long* time to lurk in preparation for spamming.
- The answer *does* include a link to a blog, but there is no indication that this blog has any affiliation to the poster.
- The answer includes substantial content other than links. That content might arguably be low quality, but it is certainly not NAA (and the correct behavior for low quality real answers is downvoting, not deletion).
- None of the user's other visible posts, anywhere on the network, reference this blog.
- The cited blog, according to GoDaddy's WHOIS, is registered in Arizona, but the link on the user's profile indicates that they are in California.
- The link on the user's profile goes to a page that shows a blog that is other than the blog that they cited.
- The post recommends a tool, but the tool recommended is an *Oracle* tool. Am I really to understand that the poster was spamming *for Oracle*?

Comment: can you screenshot the answer in question for us lowly sub 10k people

Comment: The answer has 2 downvotes and the question is 1,5 years old. Possibly that user posted the same answer to multiple questions. But that still doesn't mean it's spam.

Comment: For what it's worth, the answer [wasn't caught](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?username=aenon*&commit=Search) by [MetaSmoke](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/)'s [smoke detector](https://charcoal-se.org/).

Comment: From the posts score, it looks like at most two spam flags, one of which was by a moderator.

Comment: Golden rule, if the question is tagged [foo] then never say "If you *have* to use foo".  Foo fans don't enjoy the eye rolling and they'll find something not to like about the post.

Comment: @HansPassant perhaps, but that is worth at most a downvote, not a spam flag.

Comment: According to the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46554067/timeline) the second downvote came with the spam deletion.

Comment: @SurajRao I can't view the timeline, it says Page Not Found.

Comment: here https://imgur.com/p9zVCey

Comment: doesn't look like spam to me, tbh. But maybe i've just become desensitised from seeing more blatant spam all day.

Comment: That answer smells of an off topic question. And smells should always lead you to view the original question and answer.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I don't think that was spam. It was flagged as such by a community member, and a moderator used their hard spam flag to destroy that answer, but you're right that this has none of the marks of spam.

I've cleared the spam flags and lifted your ban. I've pinged the moderator who destroyed this post to see if they picked up something we all missed, but I don't see any connection between the blog post and this user.

Comment: Maybe undisclosed affiliation?

Comment: If there was an undisclosed affiliation, it would be helpful to understand *how* the mod discovered this affiliation, and how reviewers could independently discover the affiliation for themselves if given this answer as a review audit. If only a mod using special *leet* mod-only tools can reasonably discover this, the answer might still be spam but it should be excluded from review audits. Audits are supposed to be solvable or even obvious.

Comment: @RobertColumbia, the audit posts are picked up automatically from these types of events because they are mostly obvious (and in cases when they aren't some poor schmo fails the audit and goes "whaaaat?" on meta).  It is hard to have audits which are autogenerated that won't occasionally be non-obvious (even though the heuristic tries to make them be obvious).

Comment: What dave said. It's good that you brought it up on meta @RobertColumbia, that way the audit can be removed before it catches other people. These things happen and when they do they get remedied here.

Comment: @ivarni ty, I know that audits are autogenerated. What I was saying is that if this answer is ruled to be spam anyway, it either needs to be excluded from audits as a non-obvious case, or an explanation is needed as to how reviewers could discover its spamminess (e.g. "You could have discovered the undisclosed affiliation by cross-referencing the poster's record at the Internet Transnational Registry of Website Affiliations and noting that the poster's entry there includes a Twitter handle that is referenced in a hidden comment in the source code of the blog that they linked to. QED, spam.").

Comment: I totally understand that not all spam is the obvious dietary supplement, overseas pharmacy, and fake ID stuff, but expecting a reviewer to discover that, hey, the poster's second cousin once dated someone with a 20% ownership interest in a company that once provided services to the blog writer's father in 1987, and then have the keenly mod-aligned judgment to conclude that that relationship is so close that it constitutes sufficient affiliation for any citation of such blog to constitute spam unless said relationship is duly documented and filed on Form 22-Bravo-Lima, that is not reasonable.